# How to copy table by spark-sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Actually, I want to move one table to another database.
But spark don't permit this.

Then, how to copy table by spark-sql?

I already tried this.

```
SELECT *
INTO table1 IN new_database
FROM old_database.table1
```

But it was not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

maybe try:

```
CREATE TABLE new_db.new_table AS
SELECT *
FROM old_db.old_table;
```

Comment: This will not preserve partitioning and storage format (still looking for a way to do so myself)

Answer (score 3):

To preserve partitioning and storage format do the following- 
Get the complete schema of the existing table by running-

```
show create table db.old_table
```

The above query will output the table schema which you can just execute after changing the path name and table name. 
Then insert all the rows into the new blank table using-

```
insert into db.new_table select * from db.old_table
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will create a new table while preserving the definition of the "old" table.

```
CREATE TABLE db.new_table LIKE db.old_table;
```

For more info, check the doc's [`CREATE TABLE`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-like.html).